# C++ std::vector Optimization Across Two Classes

Tags: c++, class, vector

```
class B
{
public:
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > vec;

    void AtoB(const std::vector<int> &v)
    {
        vec.push_back(v);
    }
}
```

Class B above holds the data.

```
class A
{
public:
    B* pSomeB;

    void fnA()
    {
        std::vector<int> v;
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            v.push_back(rand());
        }

        pSomeB->AtoB(v);
    }

    void fnB()
    {
        pSomeB->push_back(std::vector<int>());

        std::vector<int> &v(pSomeB->vec[pSomeB->vec.size()-1]);
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            v.push_back(rand());
        }
    }
  }
```

Class A has a pointer to the instance of Struct B. A::fnA() and A::fnB() achieve the same in a different way.

If we call fnA the vector is constructed locally, then passed on by ref and then copied into B::vec. If we call fnB it fetches a reference to the vector that is inserted into vecB, so we go outside our scope, but we bypass the need to construct and copy later and construct right into the target.

Now class design standards set aside from a pure theoretical level. Should fnB therefore not be more efficient? Especially noticeable if the vector grows larger? I was surprised to see that fnB resulted in a considerably larger executable. If anyone had some insight on this that would be really helpful!

**Edit** due to the helpful comments below I unfortunately have to point out that std::move is not an option because one of the requirements is for the project code to work prior to C++0x/C++11

Comment: `pSomeB->push_back(...)` and `pSomeB[pSomeB->size()-1]` won't compile. `fnB()` doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: `fnA` and `AtoB` could conspire to move the vector, rather than copying it. Then it should be as efficient as `fnB` (after the latter is made to compile, that is). `void AtoB(std::vector<int>&& v) { vec.push_back(std::move(v));}` and `pSomeB->AtoB(std::move(v));`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Small oversight when writing the SO code. I have corrected it and also noted that std::move is not an option, this is a question based purely on what is provided. I would like to understand what is happening.

Comment: Pre-C++, you could do `vec.push_back(std::vector<int>()); vec.back.swap(v);` This requires `AtoB` to take a non-const reference. It's a poor man's `move`, essentially.

Answer (score 0):

When corrected, I understand your code as `fnB` trying to modify B's vector directly instead of doing the same through `fnA`

If you question is: Is it more efficient to do so?
The answer is: it's not as it breaks encapsulation (one in `A` should not see what inside `B` as it prevents changing `B` later without changing `A`)

Please notice that even in `fnB` you're creating an empty vector, you're re-allocating the 2D array (with `push_back` as I *guess* you intended).

So your code is currently doing, at worst, 102 allocations in `fnA` (one for std::vector, 100 to push back ints, and one to fit the vector in B's vector). That's the same count in `fnB`.

The only (few) things you can do to improve the speed of your code, is to:

1. Resize the vector if you know beforehand its size (this is the greatest (hidden) cost of your code: allocations), then instead of appending, use operator []
2. Use move instead of copying (avoid making a copy)
3. Or use pointers and unique_ptr instead of plain objects (for example `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>>>`) if you are not confident with writing moving code by yourself.

The interface could look like:

```
struct B
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>>> array;
    void append(std::vector<int> * v) { array.push_back(v); }

    std::vector<int> & operator[] (const size_t index) { return *array[index]; }
};

struct A
{
    B & b;
    void fnA() {
        // One allocation here
        std::vector<int> * v = new std::vector<int>;
        v->reserve(100);  // Another allocation here
        for(size_t i = 0; i < 100; v++) {
            (*v)[i] = rand();
        }
        b.append(v); // Final allocation here => it's optimal
    }

    void exampleUse() { int i = b[0][2]; }
    [...]
};
```

Comment: Instead of using resize you can also use vector::reserve to set the capacity, and then still use push_back.

Comment: @jhauris That's true, but then size() is not valid. I've changed the code example.

Comment: @xryl669 I am well aware that pointers can be used. Move is not an option
. The vector size and vector allocation are purely for illustration purposes. I assume that the biggest cost would be copying the local vector created in A into B::vec inside of B::AtoB that gets called when using A::fnA()

Comment: @SirRogers The greatest cost is actually the allocation. Copying `int` is the smallest and fastest operation you can do on a CPU. Try to profile it, you'll see. So to avoid allocations, you need to either use pointers (and below use `unique_ptr` so moving & deallocating is done for you) or add move semantics (which might be a PITA if you have to change the interface everywhere)